# Error in deploying mobicents chat server (sip servlet)

Tags: tomcat, servlets, chat, sip

I am new to Sip Servlets.
I have followed the following steps from http://www.mobicents.org/chatserver.html:

1. Downloaded war file given in the above link (chatroom-servlet-1.6.0.FINAL.war)into your tomcat_home/webapps directory.
2. Drop the dar file in tomcat_home/conf/dars directory.
   Dar file content: 
       MESSAGE: ("org.mobicents.servlet.sip.example.ChatroomApplication","DAR:From",       "ORIGINATING", "", "NO_ROUTE", "0")
       REGISTER: ("org.mobicents.servlet.sip.example.ChatroomApplication", "DAR:From", "ORIGINATING", "", "NO_ROUTE", "0")
3. specified in the Service xml tag, darConfigurationFileLocation attribute of the tomcat_home/conf/server.xml file : conf/dars/chatserver-dar.properties
4. Then ran Tomcat and on browser gave URL: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/chatroom-servlet-1.6.0.FINAL"

There is no error while running tomcat server but after running the application browser says 404 Page not found. 
Please help me to resolve this issue. I am trying with both tomcat and JBoss but not able to run the application in both.

Comment: This application is actually pretty old. There was no webpage on it, you could only join the chatroom via SIP clients. Try the new WebRTC powered chat application (limited to 1 to 1 conversations for now, but you can contribute multi participants), read from https://code.google.com/p/sipservlets/wiki/HTML5WebRTCVideoApplication

Comment: Can this application get integrated with IP Multimedia Subsystem (IMS) in the way that RTP can flow through IMS?

Comment: Yes it can but this is more advanced, you can have a look at http://www.telestax.com/metaswitch-telestax-offer-cloud-based-ims-core-web-apis/, there is instructions at the end (RestComm in this article is a SIP Servlets application)

Answer (score 0):

This servlet doesn't answer to HTTP requests. It is supposed to work with SIP clients, exchanging messages between them. I think you missed this last part of the page you linked:

> How to play with it Starts Two SIP Chat Clients. Point them to
>   sip:just4fun@127.0.0.1:5080  Type your message and then click on the
>   send button You should see the messages in both clients once they are
>   both in the chat server (that is when they sent at least one message
>   to it).